# enable android PhoneaAccount after telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount()

Tags: android, connection, account

I've managed to register a new `PhoneAccount` without exceptions or errors and I get the "*Calling Account settings*" activity. However, I can't see my `PhoneAccount` anywhere so I can't enable it.

My `TelecomManager` seems to have the `phoneAccount`, because I can get it with `getPhoneAccount(PhoneAccountHandle)`.

I don't know what the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, it is a Samsung problem. The solution is here [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-contrib/C7qbnnAGzsk)