# Implement a system managed ConnectionService

Tags: android

i want to implement this for adding incoming call and different operations on an ongoing call like holding rejecting etc.

I have already viewed and implemeted the following but got

> FATAL EXCEPTION:java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user!

[Android: Implement a custom ConnectionService which uses built-in telephony stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36889180/android-implement-a-custom-connectionservice-which-uses-built-in-telephony-stac)

Comment: can you please provide more information? and some code examples as well please?

Comment: As i am not getting the right way to use this System managed Connection Service:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html

Secondly how this can be enabled 
System managed ConnectionServices must be enabled by the user in the phone app settings

Comment: Felix  Have you got any clue to this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can not enable your `PhoneAccount` programatically.
Please, check my post: 
[Enable phoneAcco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41699798/enable-android-phoneaaccount-after-telecommanager-registerphoneaccount)

Comment: Where exactly should I put that verification when Samsung?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean. The link I posted shows a piece of code that is used for request the user to enable your application phone account. The problem is that Samsung doesn't recognize the intent `TelecomManager.ACTION_CHANGE_PHONE_ACCOUNTS`, so you must use a special intent. Then on an activity, you can call `startActivity(yourIntent)` to show the _Manage PhoneAccounts_ settings where users can enable or disable created phoneAccounts