# How to fix java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user?

Tags: android-connectionservice

I had the below given code working for me to make a self managed connecion service. But this has stopped working with this error:

> java.lang.SecurityException: This PhoneAccountHandle is not enabled for this user!

Code:

```
class CallManager(context: Context) {
val telecomManager: TelecomManager
var phoneAccountHandle: PhoneAccountHandle
var context: Context

init {
    telecomManager = context.getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE) as TelecomManager
    this.context = context

    val componentName = ComponentName(this.context, ConnService::class.java)
    phoneAccountHandle = PhoneAccountHandle(componentName,"com.darkhorse.videocalltest")
}

fun register(){
    val phoneAccount = PhoneAccount.builder(phoneAccountHandle,"com.darkhorse.videocalltest")
        .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER) .setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CONNECTION_MANAGER).build()
    telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount)
}

fun incomingCall(caller: String?){
    val callInfo = Bundle()
    callInfo.putString("from", caller)
    telecomManager.addNewIncomingCall(phoneAccountHandle,callInfo)
    Log.i("incomingCall", "incomingCall")
}
}
```

I am sure the same code was working fine earlier.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46097092/implement-a-system-managed-connectionservice) doesn't help.

Comment: Having same issue. Did you find any solution?

Comment: https://github.com/lakshaydulani/android-connectionservice-kotlin-basic @SoftSan

Answer (score 1):

`registerPhoneAccount()`

**Example:**

```java
PhoneAccountHandle phoneAccountHandle = new PhoneAccountHandle(new ComponentName(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),MyConnectionService.class.getName()),"TestApp");
TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELECOM_SERVICE);
PhoneAccount.Builder builder = new PhoneAccount.Builder(phoneAccountHandle, "TestApp");
builder.setCapabilities(PhoneAccount.CAPABILITY_CALL_PROVIDER);
PhoneAccount phoneAccount = builder.build();
telecomManager.registerPhoneAccount(phoneAccount);
```

To enable the `PhoneAccount`

**Example:**

```java
Intent intent=new Intent();
intent.setClassName("com.android.server.telecom","com.android.server.telecom.settings.EnableAccountPreferenceActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```